# About money making/earnings

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, money

Is money making or earning for online platforms like youtube and instagram and other halal or haram, any reference to this. My friend want to start a youtube channel but got confused about earnings on this way.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, without concrete evidence, everything is considered halal. However, if an individual's earnings are based on haram elements, such as objectionable material like music, inappropriate images of women that provoke desire, false and deviant beliefs, riba-based banks, permissive websites, haram movies, and the like, then the income is considered haram by default. The effort put into earning such income does not justify its haram status.

If an individual is earning money from platforms like YouTube, Instagram, or Facebook, based on the monetization of their channel and ads, it would be considered haram income, even if they have filtered their ad preferences for halal/permissible means. This is because the platform itself regulates the ads, and there is no policy that complies with Islamic principles. As a result, there is a risk of haram ads appearing on an individual's channel, and thus it is advised to refrain from earning money from these platforms to avoid consuming haram provisions.

If most of the ads accompanying an individual's content are permissible ads, then there is no sin in making money from these ads. However, if this is not the case, an individual must stop offering this service, as they would be promoting and spreading sin.

***Proofs in one video*** :->
[Assim al hakeem](https://youtu.be/O_O0pVu7CeM)

***Hadith*** :->

> ........... "عَمْرُو إِنِّي أُرِيدُ أَنْ أَبْعَثَكَ عَلَى جَيْشٍ
> فَيُغْنِمُكَ اللَّهُ وَأَرْغَبُ لَكَ رَغْبَةً مِنَ الْمَالِ
> صَالِحَةً"...... ["يَا عَمْرُو نِعْمَ الْمَالُ الصَّالِحِ لِلْمَرْءِ
> الصَّالِحِ](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2021/02/20/halal-wealth-excellent/)
>
> ‘Amr ibn al-‘As reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon
> him, sent for me and he ordered me to put on my armor and weapons,
> then come to him. I did so and came to him while he was performing
> ablution. The Prophet raised his eyes to me, then lowered them and he
> said, “O ‘Amr, I intend to send you at the head of an army and Allah
> will award you with spoils. I will give you an appropriate portion of
> the property.” ‘Amr said, “I did not embrace Islam in hopes of earning
> spoils, but rather I submitted in hopes of Islam and to be with the
> Messenger of Allah.” The Prophet said, “O ‘Amr, lawful wealth is
> excellent for a righteous man.”
>
> Source: al-Adab al-Mufrad 297
>
> Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Albani.

***Hadith*** :->

> Al-Nu’man ibn Bashir reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and
> blessings be upon him, said, “The lawful is clear and the unlawful is
> clear, and between the two of them are doubtful matters about which
> many people do not know. Thus, he who avoids doubtful matters clears
> himself in regard to his religion and his honor, and he who falls into
> doubtful matters will fall into the unlawful as the shepherd who
> pastures near a sanctuary, all but grazing therein. Verily, every king
> has a sanctum and the sanctum of Allah is His prohibitions. Verily, in
> the body is a piece of flesh which, if sound, the entire body is
> sound, and if corrupt, the entire body is corrupt. Truly, it is the
> heart.”
>
> Source: [Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 52, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 1599](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2011/02/14/halal-haram-clear/)
>
> Grade: Muttafaqun Alayhi (authenticity agreed upon) according to
> Al-Bukhari and Muslim.

***Quran*** :->

> ......."Cooperate with one another in goodness and righteousness, and
> do not cooperate in sin and transgression. And be mindful of Allah.
> Surely Allah is severe in punishment"  [5:2](https://quran.com/5/2)

*To begin, it is essential to understand where the money for a YouTube channel comes from. When someone watches a video you've uploaded, YouTube displays advertisements during the video. YouTube primarily earns revenue from this, and you get a small portion of it. According to scholars, the money you receive will be considered haram if the advertisements contain anything that is impermissible or unIslamic, such as offensive music or language. Therefore, it is advisable to avoid monetizing your YouTube channel. Instead, you could create high-quality content, seek sponsorship, and uphold Shariah.
In AdSense, you can never be sure what the ad contains or what product it promotes through a website. It could be a jacket made of pigskin, a food supplement that contains pig meat or alcohol, or toys and music or interest-based products that are inappropriate or contain pictures of women or men. Hence, it is better to refrain from doing so.*

**Rather than arguing about doubtful and vulnerable things, seek lawful income and make dua to Allah Azzawajal to grant you success in this world and the hereafter.**